# Appleのアプリ審査で、古いバージョンのnend広告が残っていると指摘されお手上げ状態です。

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-x

以前nend広告を導入していたのですが、現在は使用しておりません。
nendに関するファイルはすべて取り除いたのですが、Apple Review Teamに古いバージョンのnend広告が残っていると何度もリジェクトされていて、お手上げ状態です。

以下は、これまでやってきたことです。

・プロジェクトのルートフォルダでnendというキーワードで検索しましたが、見つかりませんでした。(nendを導入していたときは、ここにNendModule.mmなどのファイルが表示されていました。)

・XCodeのテキスト検索機能でnendを探しても、見つかりませんでした。(onEndや、MemberonEndという文字列が誤検出されましたが、nendとは関係のないものでした。)

・otoolを使ってバイナリにnendが含まれていないか調べましたが、見つかりませんでした。

```
otool -L SlotGameiOS | grep nend
```

AppleReviewTeamに「原因となっている具体的なファイル名を教えてくれませんか」と問い合わせても、そのような指摘はできない、nend sdkを取り除いてくださいと言われております。

どんな些細なことでも良いで、情報をいただければ助かります。

Comment: TARGET - Build Phases - Copy Bundle Resourcesでnend関連ファイルがコピー対象として残ってるか確認するくらいしか思い付かねーなあ。あとはオーガナイザのArchivesでipaファイルをExportする。ipaは圧縮ファイルで解凍後のpayloadフォルダにあるappファイルは「パッケージの内容を表示」すると中身を見られる。この中にnend関連のものが含まれてないか実際に確認するとか

Answer (score 2):

nendのSDKのクラス名は「NAD～」なので、「nend」というキーワードだけ探しても不十分じゃないでしょうか?
例えば、アイコン広告を表示するためのNADIconViewクラス、NADIconLoaderクラス、あるいはそれらで使用されているメソッドと同じ名前がどこかにあるのかもしれません。

どうしてもわからなければ、nendの広告を削除するのではなくて、むしろnendの最新版SDKを使ってnendの広告を表示するようにしてみた方がよいかもしれません。
それでリジェクトされるようであれば、nendに問い合わせ、あなたが作ったアプリやプロジェクトをnendに直接見てもらって原因究明に協力してもらえばよいと思います。
nendの最新版SDKは正式にAppleの承認を得ていますので、nendも問題ないと判断すればnendから直接Appleに確認してくれるかもしれません。